# python foursquare - SSL3 certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, foursquare

I'm trying to make a userless request to the Foursquare API using Mike Lewis' Python wrapper - https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare:

```
client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id=Client_ID, client_secret=Client_Secret)
categs = client.venues.categories()
```

**Intermittently**, I get a "Error connecting to Foursquare API" msg.  Running a logger to catch a more detailed message produces:

"SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

This didn't use to happen and occurs both on my local Windows development machine and on a server running ubuntu.  Am I missing something basic here about security certificates?  The problem is intermittent and sometimes just leaving it a minute and retrying fixes the problem temporarily.

I've downloaded the latest 20120716 version of the wrapper although in the code for init.py it still says API_VERSION = '20120608'.  I'm using Python 2.73 and have also signed up for the Foursquare API key, using the id and secret in the above code.  I listed the urls, using my local IP:8000 and tried using separate keys for the local and dev machines but this seems to make no difference.

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I encountered the exact same problem yesterday. I searched a lot and tried a lot, and seem the following strategy works for my case (I'm not 100% sure but it's not reporting the error any longer).

1) Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

2) Go to your Python httplib2 dir. Mine is at 
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2`

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2
```

3) Back up the current certificate

```
cp cacerts.txt backup_cacerts.txt
```

4) And then copy the downloaded file there and rename it as `cacerts.txt`

```
mv cacert.pem cacerts.txt
```

That's it.

Hope it helps. If not recover from the backup file and try other methods.

My foursquare scripts work all right after I change this : )

Comment: This solution also works for the `requests` package by replacing the site-packages/requests/cacert.pem file.

Comment: And also works for boto in `site-packages/boto/cacerts/cacerts.txt`

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Works inside virtual environment too. Make sure the downloaded cacerts.txt is located at the base of the httplib2 package folder.

Comment: Is it just me or does downloading something like this over http seem rather strange to anybody else?

Comment: @mlissner: Not to mention that you are downloading it from a site with the word 'hax' in the URL!

Comment: there seems to be no package named httplib2 under site-packages directory, why? and where i should put this pem file?

Answer (score 0):

Install or upgrade the `certifi` package:

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

This is the solution recommended by `urllib3` (which is used by many projects including `requests`, which in turn is used by the foursquare library linked above and many other libraries): http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#certificate-verification

If you need to use this for a packages which doesn't use urllib3, but httplib2 for example, you copy the `certifi/cacerts.pem` file to the `httplib2/cacerts.txt`. The directories to copy from/to can be found by doing:

```
python -c 'import httplib2; import os.path; print(os.path.dirname(httplib2.__file__))'

python -c 'import certifi; import os.path; print(os.path.dirname(certifi.__file__))'
```

If you are just using `urllib2`, then the `httplib2/` directory is not used, but a system location. You can check the files being loooked with the something like following:

```
strace python -c "import urllib2; urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://google.com/'))" 2>&1 | grep 'open' | grep 'cert'
```